# System.AccessViolationException in WPF while launching Avaya proactive dialer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, avaya

Our customers are getting the below error when they launch avaya proactive dialer from my WPF application.

Application: APPLUI.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.

```
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
Stack:
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at APPLUI.App.Main()
```

Can anyone suggest what might be causing this error?

Comment: if this is still an issue, could you please add the code where you open that program? Also [this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1604596/937093)